# Unit Testing and Framework

Tags: unit-testing, testing

I recently had an argument with my supervisor about unit testing. My office is currently working on DRs for an upcoming release and he has created a DR process.  One of the steps is to develop a unit test for your DR.  This is where we differ greatly in opinion.  He told me that this test is performed through the user interface and that the difference between functional and unit testing is that unit tests are more localized.  I am of the opinion that a unit test has to be code based because it should only test a single part of the code and this is the only way to isolate it.  I also said that unit tests were almost exclusively done in frameworks (such as jUnit) for every part of development e.g. development or maintenance.  I would like some people to weigh in on this.  Can unit testing be done through the user interface of an application?  What is the most common way to achieve unit testing?

*Note:  Yes, I did google it but most of what I found was vague enough to accommodate both of our conflicting ideas.  I am looking for more real world answers. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Unit Testing doesn't have to mean its automated (ie "code based"). Note: this is a semantic argument is mostly pointless.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin: it's not pointless. You may run different types of tests with different schedule. So choosing the right category is a serious decision. PS: unit tests ought to be automated. Cannot imagine a manual unit test.

Comment: @zerkms - the boss wants a test done through the user interface, the fact that he is calling it a unit test (when it's not really), is a semantic argument, and thus, pointless. Proving that he is misnaming the type of test he wants accomplishes nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He's wrong. A unit test is a unit test because it isolates dependencies and tests a single aspect of your code. A test that runs through your user interface isn't a unit test simply because even displaying the UI involves dozens of dependent interactions, none of which you can isolate or control for the duration of your test.

Testing frameworks are irrelevant. You can be using a "unit testing" framework and still write something that's not a unit test. For example, you write a test that writes a file to the file system, and you assert that the file exists. Well, your file system is a dependency that you didn't isolate. You wrote an *integration test*, not a unit test.

Comment: I hardly call a test that involves FS IO an *integration test*.

Comment: It is. Your file system represents an external dependency. So does the current date, for that matter.

Comment: I have never heard any *integration testing* definition that would fit it: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/48265